# Создать один AsyncTask для всех запросов

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Какие существуют методы, позволяющие использовать один AsyncTask для разных запросов?

Если учесть, что есть необходимость вызывать разные функции из разных классов в `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Трудно что-то предожить без контекста, сам AsyncTask и так достаточно кастомизируем для того чтобы прокинуть разные типы в onPostExecute. Например я бы предожил посмотреть на Retrofit который умеет сам выполнять запросы асинхронно и прокидывать данные на главный поток. Что вы используете для выыполнения запросов?

Comment: OkHttp3. Нужно выполнять запросы к API из разных участков кода, используя разные типы соединения (POST, GET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У OKHTP есть свой механизм асинхронно выполнения запросов, описан тут https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get 
В большинстве случаев когда делаете небольшие запросы - скорее всего этого будет достаточно, нежели еще оборачивать AsyncTask. Этот же механизм использует Retrofit при асинхронном вызове.

Comment: В этом случае, как я понимаю, количество запросов = количество конструкций OkHttp. А хочется иметь один класс, в который нужно передать название метода (String), тип соединения (String), параметры (Map), и он его выполнит, а после будет вызвана функция в исходном классе (инициаторе запроса).

Comment: Вообще нетипизированные запросы - плохая практика, так как при изменении параметров или долгосрочной поддержки это будет вести к тому что вам надо будет поддерживать большое количество "магических" констант. Как раз Retrofit сам генерит весь бойлерплейт, поэтому у вас может быть как раз одна точка определения имен параметров и названия метода вызова.

Comment: То есть корректнее для каждого метода API писать свой механизм запроса?

Comment: Принятая практика: используя Retrofit делаем описание каждого метода и возвращаемой модели, делаем отдельный слой ViewModel или Presetner в котором логика которая запрашивает данные и отображает их, обрабатывает реакции. Скорее всего будет несколько мапперов из модели сервисов в ViewModel и биндинг ViewModel во View.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.